# How are journaled data blocks flushed to their actual locations on storage device?

Tags: linux-kernel, ext4, journaling

Consider that a transaction 'A' is committed to journal in Ext4 filesystem. Now, when and how are the blocks, which were part of this transaction, stored to their actual locations on the storage device?

One approach can be to flush these blocks (which are cached in RAM) to their actual locations on the storage device after the journal commit has happened. Once all blocks have been flushed, remove the journal entry corresponding these blocks.

Does journal checkpointing differ from above approach?

Basically, I am not able to understand how exactly blocks, part of a journal transaction, are stored on their actual location on the storage device.

I have read few research papers and looked into course slides that explain journaling but I have a very unclear picture of this concept.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that since this is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic], it will likely be closed soon. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for specific programming questions. For system administration / linux questions, you may be able to post on one on the linux sites, like Super User, Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, or Server Fault, but be sure to check with their content guidelines before asking.

Comment: An answer probably depends on the filesystem involved. E.G. I would expect UBIFS to perform journalling slightly different than NTFS because of the (typical) storage media involved.  BTW your repeated references to "*disk*" are antiquated.